# What's the name of this kind of transition?

Tags: transitions

What's the name of this fancy transition between views (listview and detailview here)? Is it Transition Morphing?

[image: Listview]

[image: morph]

[image: morph]

[image: detailview]

Answer (score 3):

I have always known this as *expanding card*, and you can search Google for that term and find examples and code to do it.

However, Material Design used to call it that way, but in the new site version they call it *[parent-child transition](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior)*.

> A card expands to fill the full screen using a parent-child
>   transition.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally just referred to as an "animated transition". Here you're transitioning between card and detail view, as you noted, but I don't think there's any special moniker for the transition style other than *animated*.